# Eliminate duplicate Json elements and retrieve element names starting with capital letters spring boot/java

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, type-conversion, pojo

I'm developing a Rest Client using Spring Boot and Spring Framework (spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.6.RELEASE) 
I have a class representing a response object as shown below:

```
public class ValidateResponse {
    private String ResponseCode;
    private String ResponseDesc;

    //getters and setters
    //constructors using fields
    //empty constructor
}
```

I'm creating a web-hook for an external api and I need to return a JSON object to for a specific endpoint (the JSON object properties must start with uppercase(s)). I'm calling returning the object from a `PostMapping` method nested in a `RequestMapping` root path:

```
@PostMapping("hooks/validate")
public ValidateResponse responseObj(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headersObj) {
    ValidateResponse response = new ValidateResponse("000000", "Success");

    logger.info("Endpoint = hooks/validate | Request Headers = {}", headersObj);

    return response;

}
```

However, when I hit the endpoint from postman I'm getting duplicate varialbes

```
{
    "ResponseCode": "000000",
    "ResponseDesc": "Success",
    "responseCode": "000000",
    "responseDesc": "Success"
}
```

I understand that the pojo-json conversion is handled by spring but I don't understand why the conversion is yielding duplicate variables.

**Note:** I know the `ResponseDesc` and the `ResponseCode` are not declared using the best standards for naming variables (camelCasing).

I've done some digging and according to the  [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

and

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

So, I'm assuming its syntactically correct to define a variable using the `Camelcase` format [Need clarification on this].

I'm considering having to create the JSON object manually but I'd like to know the cause of this behaviour first. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ValidateResponse {

    @JsonProperty("ResponseDesc")
    public String responseCode;

    @JsonProperty("ResponseDesc")
    public String responseDesc;

    //getters and setters
    //constructors using fields
    //empty constructor
}
```

This must fix your problem, however I do not know the reason as it requires deep Jackson investigation.

**EDIT**

I found out the reason.
The field got duplicated because in you case you had:

- 2 public fields named in upper case -> they are to be processed by jackson
- 2 getters `getResponseCode` and `getResponseDesc` -> they are to be resolved 
  as accessors for properties `responseCode` and `responseDesc` accordingly.

Summing this up - you have 4 properties resolved by Jackson. Simply making your fields private will resolve your issue, however I still advise using `JsonProperty` approach.

Comment: I had created accessors for `ResponseCode` and `ResponseDesc` to specifically return `ResponseCode` and `ResponseDesc` but Jackson resolves additional `responseDesc` and `responseCode` fields.

Comment: Adding the @JsonProperty annotation above the fields and adding the ("property_name") value to the annotation solved it!

Comment: @JuneM3ta in any case I would make the fields themselves private, because there is no need to create accessors otherwise

Comment: I've set the fields to private

Answer (score 2):

`Jackson` deserializes all the public fields that it comes across. However if you want `Jackson` to return the response in your expected element names (in your case elements starting with capital letters), make the fields `private` and annotate them with the `@JsonProperty(expected_name_here)`. Your class file will typically looks as shown below

```
public class ValidateResponse {

    @JsonProperty("ResponseDesc")
    private String responseCode;

    @JsonProperty("ResponseDesc")
    private String responseDesc;

    //getters and setters
    //constructors using fields
    //empty constructor
}
```

> Note: The getters and setters for these fields should be `public`, otherwise `Jackson` won't see anything to deserialize in the class.

Comment: I was using the @JsonProperty annotation above the fields without the (expected_name) value. Adding the value to the annotation solves the issue

Comment: But what's the point of getter and setter if you are indeed making the fields public ?

Comment: I've set the fields to private

Answer (score 0):

I added a `com.google.code.gson` dependency in the projects `pom.xml` file to configure Spring Boot to use Gson (instead of the default jackson).

The Json object returned from the `hooks/validate` endpoint must have its property names starting with a capital letter. Using a java class to generate the response object was resulting to `camelCased` property names so I resolved to create the JSON response object manually. Here's the code for creating the custom JSON object:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> responseObj(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headersObj) {

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
    response.addProperty("ResponseCode", "00000000");
    response.addProperty("ResponseDesc" , "Success");

    logger.info("Endpoint = hooks/validate | Request Headers = {}", headersObj);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(response.toString());

}
```

**Note** The JSON object is returned as a `String` so the response from the endpoint must have an additional header to define `MediaType` to inform the calling system that the response is in JSON format:

```
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

then add the header to the response:

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(response.toString());
```